# Open Browser and Navigate to a specific folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have mentioned my code below, I need it to navigate to the folder mentioned in the folder open section. It opens the browser but not navigating to the mentioned folder.(Its at the bottom of this code) Can anyone please help.

```
            `window.open('file:///C:/D/Topwill%20Second%20Phase/Progamming%20Files/SampleTestings/uploads/', '_blank', features);
                    };
                    cell.appendChild(openFolderLink);
                    // Display PDF in PDF viewer
                    const pdfViewer = cell.nextElementSibling; // Get the next cell for PDF viewer
                    const embedTag = document.createElement('embed');
                    embedTag.src = response.filePath; // The URL to the uploaded file
                    embedTag.type = 'application/pdf';
                    embedTag.width = '100%';
                    embedTag.height = '100%';
                    pdfViewer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
                    pdfViewer.appendChild(embedTag);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`

This code it written to drag PDF files to a HTML interface for reference and again drag it back to a web based system
When we drag the PDF file to the HTML interface, it keeps a copy of the file in dedicated folder(uploads folder) (runs in backend)
I couldn't find a method to directly drag it back to the web based system(Payment app) as HTML interface only holds a downloadable link
What Im trying to do here is open the uploads folder and allow users to drag it from there to the payment system.
If there is a direct method to drag files to an Interface and hold it there and drag it back to another online platform that would be great!

Comment: _"This code it written to drag PDF files to a HTML interface for reference and again drag it back to a web based system"_ That should be possible.